# Set an adapter to a v7.ListPreferences

Tags: android, android-preferences

I migrated to android.support.v7.preference and I have some problems with the ListPreference item.

I had that code :

```
public class CurrencyListPreferences extends ListPreference {
    private List<Currency> mCurrencyList;
    private Context mContext;

    public CurrencyListPreferences(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CurrencyListPreferences(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public void setCurrencyList(List<Currency> currencyList) {
        this.mCurrencyList = currencyList;
    }

    protected void onPrepareDialogBuilder(Builder builder) {
        final ListAdapter listAdapter = (ListAdapter) new CurrencyAdapter(mContext, mCurrencyList, this);
        builder.setPositiveButton(null, null);
        builder.setAdapter(listAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });
    }

    public String getText() {
        return Preferences.getStringValue(mContext, TypePreference.TYPE_CURRENCYCODE);
    }
}
```

Then I had a currency adapter with show the different value needed

when I migrated to android.support.v7.preference, that code doesn't work. I have a message "ListPreference requires an entries array and an entryValues array."

onPrepareDialogBuilder isn't called anymore, is there a way to migrate my good old code ?

If there is no solution I imagined two solutions :

- Migrate to setEntries and setEntriesValues (that's sad I would loose the layout)
- Create a specific Dialog handler handled with onPreferenceTreeClick. Sounds a bit complicated for that use .. (and hard to maintain)

Regards

Comment: if you used `@Override` annotation you would see that your base class doesn't have `onPrepareDialogBuilder` method, you should probably use `android.support.v7.preference.ListPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat` or `android.support.v14.preference.ListPreferenceDialogFragment`

Comment: I can't use that two class into a Preference.xml file (of v7)

Comment: first of all why cant you use some custom class that extends `android.support.v7.preference.ListPreference`?

Comment: something like [this](http://pastebin.com/RCBtPX2m) for example?

Comment: that's work. but you can't add a friendly UI like column in my case which was possible before. it was possible before if you override onPrepareDialogBuilder and you put all the data into an adapter

Comment: so as is wrote use: `android.support.v7.preference.ListPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat` as a `Fragment` for your preference

Comment: it won't work because it doesn't inherits with the same class. you'll have that error : Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class ListPreferenceDialogFragment

Comment: see [this](http://pastebin.com/xcGfyEPp) and use `CurrencyListPreference` in res/xml/preference.xml i posted before

Comment: @P.Sohm .. could you find a solution to this issue? I am stuck with a similar issue and not able to find a solution. Thanks for any help

Comment: @Sushil I don't think there are solution. someone should backport ListPreference and it's not so simple. Btw I suggest you to use a real array with ListPreference. if you find something, it would be nice to share it :'

Comment: @P.Sohm.. thanks for your comment. I came across this : https://github.com/michael-rapp/AndroidMaterialPreferences .. This has an example to use multiselect listpreference with material design. I am evaluating if this is useful and I can use it in my project.

Comment: @sushil maybe should we create an issue on this project ?